# openpyxl from Python code throws error while trying to open .xlsx file path from a global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, openpyxl

with some help from here, I have written a python code to get input from user which is usually an excel document path and pass it on to other programs which opens the excel and do some operation.
In the below code if I give the path directly in the openpyxl, it reads the document but when I try to pass the path via a variable it throws the below error.
Could somebody help me out here?

Error -
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .xlsx" file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm

```
    import openpyxl
    import tkinter as tk
    
    class App(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
            #Create a blank dictionary
            self.answers = {}
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
    
            tk.Label(self,text="Give Input Sheet Path").grid(row=0,column=0)
            self.Input_From_User1 = tk.Entry(self)
            self.Input_From_User1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    
    
            tk.Button(self,text="Feed into Program",command = self.collectAnswers).grid(row=1,column=1)
    
        def collectAnswers(self):
            self.answers['Input_Path'] = self.Input_From_User1.get()
            global Input_Path
            Input_Path = self.answers['Input_Path']
            functionThatUsesAnswers(self.answers)
            
    
    def functionThatUsesAnswers(answers):
    print("Given Input Path ", answers['Input_Path'])
    quit()
    def quit():
        root.destroy()        
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = tk.Tk()
        App(root).grid()
        root.mainloop()
    
    print(Input_Path)
    Input_path1 = ('r"'+Input_Path+'"')
    print(Input_path1)
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Input_path1) # trying to open the open the input sheet from the below path
    #wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive - xx.xx'x xx\xxx\xx\xxxx\xxx.xlsx")
```

Comment: You need to escape the ```\```.  IOW,  use ```\\``` for each ```\``` in your path.

Comment: I replaced as suggested but Still getting the same error

Comment: You don't need the line `Input_path1 = ('r"'+Input_Path+'"')`. Just use `Input_Path` in `openpyxl.load_workbook(...)`.

Comment: Thank you @acw1668, made the changes as you suggested and it worked